# Django ORM geo function ST_AsMVTGeom always returns type "bytea" not "geometry"

Tags: postgis, django

I want to use POSTGIS function `ST_AsMVTGeom` with django ORM. Therefore I create following geo function:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Transform, GeoFunc

class AsMVTGeom(GeoFunc):
    function = "ST_AsMVTGeom"
    geom_param_pos = (0, )
    output_field = GeometryField(srid=4326)
```

and call it with following query (example bounding box):

```
mvt_geom = (
        municipality.objects
        .annotate(
            mvt_geom=AsMVTGeom(
                Transform("geom", 3857),
                Value("ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(0, 0), ST_Point(4096, 4096))"),
                4096,
                0,
                False,
            )
        )
    )
    print(str(mvt_geom.query))
```

This gives me something like this (for simple model containing a `geom` column):

```
SELECT "map_municipality"."id", "map_municipality"."ags", "map_municipality"."nuts", "map_municipality"."name", "map_municipality"."type", ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform("map_municipality"."geom", 3857), ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(0, 0), ST_Point(4096, 4096)), 4096, 0, False)::bytea AS "mvt_geom" FROM "map_municipality"
```

But as I want to use outcome in further queries, I need type of `mvt_geom` to be `geometry` not `bytea`. If I remove casting to `bytea`, everything is fine.
I somehow cannot change it to type `geometry`, trying for hours...
Even explicit casting to `GeometryField` does not help.

This user seems to have a similar problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/56475858/5804947

Comment: MapBox vector tile geometry is not PostGIS geometry. If you need geometry type in further processing, don't use AsMVTGeom. You have geometries already in the `geom` column.

Comment: In fact, i want to use above query as subquery to the following query:
`model.objects.annotate(mvt=AsMVT(Subquery(mvt_geom), Value("default"), 4096, Value("mvt_geom")))`
This only works if I remove `::bytea` from raw query. 
How can I use above query as subquery?

Comment: I guess that by dropping out AsMVT Geom from the subquery  `mvt_geom=AsMVTGeom(...`. As you can read https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVTGeom.html takes in geometries so must feed it with geometries.